# rlang::qq_show return is not same with excution

Tags: r, rlang

The question is why the `rlang::qq_show` results is not same with excution.

```r
var <- c("a = character(0)", "b = integer()", "c = double()")
rlang::qq_show(tibble::tibble(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(var)))
#> tibble::tibble(a = character(0), b = integer(), c = double())

tibble::tibble(a = character(0), b = integer(), c = double())
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # ℹ 3 variables: a <chr>, b <int>, c <dbl>

df <- tibble::tibble(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(var))
df
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # ℹ 3 variables: a = character(0) <chr>, b = integer() <int>,
#> #   c = double() <dbl>
```

The `rlang::qq_show` show the right code:

`tibble::tibble(a = character(0), b = integer(), c = double())`

but the execution does not return right variable names but right type.

For first variable, the right name should be `a` not `a = character(0)`

I review the documents [Splice operator !!!](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html)， and argument `...` in `tibble::tibble` is `dynamic-dots`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see explanation from [#1640](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/1640)

```r
exprs <- c(a = "character(0)", b = "integer()", c = "double()")
tibble::tibble(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(exprs))
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # ℹ 3 variables: a <chr>, b <int>, c <dbl>

exprs <- list(a = quote(character(0)), b = quote(integer()), c = quote(double()))
tibble::tibble(!!!exprs)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # ℹ 3 variables: a <chr>, b <int>, c <dbl>
```